# Why there is a error when I want download file from chrome using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

preferences = {"download.default_directory": "D:\sourcetree_\webscraping_example\testing", "safebrowsing.enabled": "false"}

options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.whatsapp.com/download/")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[text() = 'Download for Windows']").click()
```

There is a error (can't open file 'D:\sourcetree_\webscraping_example\Untitled-1': [Errno 2] No such file or directory) . May I know how to solve it?

Comment: Update the question with the complete error stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{"download.default_directory": r"D:\sourcetree_\webscraping_example\testing",
```

You have to escape the \ , you can use \\ , or put r"" .

Now without escaping \t will be resolved as tab

Comment: sry, i don't understand this (Now without escaping \t will be resolved as tab)

Comment: \testing , it will take \t as tab